# Sketch convert all symbols to the same color

Tags: sketch-app

In Sketch, is there a way to do a batch convert process on symbols? Is that the right approach to take for something like this -

How do you convert all symbol colors to the same color - such as white?

Comment: for clarification- you mean OTHER than editing the base symbol and changing its color?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a plugin like [Craft from Invision](https://www.invisionapp.com/craft) to replace colors (this would be the best option if you already have a complete document) or create a symbol to use as a 'color swatch' that you essentially use within all other symbols. (this is the method I'd choose if I was starting with a blank canvas.)

[image]

I personally really like [this tutorial](https://medium.com/ux-power-tools/this-is-without-a-doubt-the-coolest-sketch-technique-youll-see-all-day-ddefa65ea959) on Medium that teaches a lot of tricks with nested symbols like color swatches.

Comment: just grabbed craft.  it doesn't show the foreground color option when i select the symbols... thttps://i.gyazo.com/fd02078790432dc7c692d6b0a7169dbb.png https://gyazo.com/fd02078790432dc7c692d6b0a7169dbb

Comment: @ina I'm not exactly sure what you mean... With craft you can create a style sheet, it will import all colors used. Once you update one of those colors in the sheet, you can sync it again and the color will update throughout your document. See this: https://medium.com/@clarklab/global-color-replacement-in-sketch-7e53c51cbde0